# Browser closing issue in asp.net mvc application using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can you please help us to close the below issue

I created an exe in which we are sending a sms text containing a url with encrypted id like http:// www.google.com/Test/Testdetails?InvoiceId=123455
The customer clicks on this link to download the pdf for the respective invoice id.
The problem is once the pdf file is downloaded, the browser remains open. We need to close the browser once the user has download the file.

I tested the below code and it works in chrome 63, but when tested in chrome 64 and safari its not working

```
 Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                        Response.TransmitFile(filename);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                        Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>");  
                        //return Redirect("/Home/Index");
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();
```

Comment: Response.End() does what it says: end the response. This mean the code you put afte Response.End() is not executed: no javascript code is sent back to the browser. Note that even if you send it somehow, browser will not execute it: in your case it will try to handle a pdf (saving it on disk, or displaying to the user), and in that context html code has no meaning

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`setTimeout(function(){ window.close; }, 1000);`( **timeout > 300.**)

**OR** 
`open(location, '_self').close();`

**Example:**

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                        Response.TransmitFile(filename);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                        Response.Write("<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.close; }, 1000);");  
                        //return Redirect("/Home/Index");
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();
```

Comment: can you please provide syntax

Comment: Thanks you for replying. its not closing still.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to how the browser decides to handle the Response you are sending bak (mainly, according to the Response Headers youset).

You are in the hand of the browser, and actually you found that the same code you use pruduce different results according to different versions of the same browser.

What about let the browser be out of the game?
You have created the exe that need to download the file, you can download the file from the exe itself

As example:
your server code can be something like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
Response.TransmitFile(filename);
//Response.Flush(); no need for flush, Response.End will do it
Response.End();
```

in the client exe, you have different options. E.g. `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest`, other classes able to handle httprequests.

Using `WebClient` can be as simple as this:

```
string urlToGet = "yourUrl";
string filePath = .... //as your user where to save it, or whatever you want
try
{
    new WebClient().DowloadFile(urlToGet, filePath);
}
catch(System.Exception exc)
{
//error downloading file, hanle it somehow.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but my understanding of your ans is once the downloaded completed that window closed by using client side exe?. if yes then can you let me know how to create client side exe